# Bloquear el acceso al los discos de Ubuntu que se llamen sda Shell Script

Tags: bash, ubuntu, shell, shell-script

Buenas tardes resulta que tengo un código el  cual se trata de formatear un disco con mkfs y dd pero lo que no quiero es que pueda bloquear los discos que sean sda, sda1, etc.

```
echo "Listando discos disponibles..."
sudo lsblk | grep 'disk\|part'

sleep 5

echo "1. Formatear Disco o Particion con MKFS."
echo "2. Formatear Disco con  dd."
echo "3. Mostrar Discos y Particiones Disponible."
echo "4. Salir."

read -p "Elige una opcion : " DISCOFOR

if [ $DISCOFOR -eq 1 ] 

    then

        echo "1. Formatear disco o particion en ext4."
        echo "2. Formatear disco o particion en ext3."
        echo "3. Formatear disco o particion en ntfs."
        echo "4. Formatear disco o particion en fat32."

        read -p "Elige una opcion : " OPCIONDISCO

        read -p "Cual disco deseas formatear : " ELIMIDISCO

        REGLA='sda[1-9]$'

        if [[ $ELIMIDISCO =~ "^[sda]" ]]

             then

                    echo "No puedes formatear $ELIMIDISCO porque es el disco del sistema"
                    sleep 3
                    
        else

                echo "Esto no funciona"
                sleep 2

        fi      

elif [ $DISCOFOR -eq 2 ]

       then

            echo "Formatear con dd"

elif [ $DISCOFOR -eq 3 ]

      then

            echo "Listando discos disponibles..."
            sudo lsblk | grep 'disk\|part'
            sleep 5

elif [ $DISCOFOR -eq 4 ]

        then

            echo "Saliendo..."
            sleep 3

else

    echo "Elige una opcion entre el rango 1 y 4"

fi
```

El programa no esta terminado y no quiero que lo termine solo quiero saber en que estoy fallando en la expresión regular para que los disco sda con sus particiones entre en la condición, porque siempre entra en el else y pone que esto no funciona ya que no me lo coge

`if [[ $ELIMIDISCO =~ "^[sda]" ]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como te he sugerido en el chat a mi me funciona así:

```
if [[ $ELIMIDISCO =~ ^sda ]];
```

es decir, sin corchetes ni comillas.

Prueba a ver.

Comment: lo voy a comprobar

Comment: pero ojo porque no siempre los discos del sistema son `sda*`... si usas LVM pueden tener otros nombres como en mi caso, que se llama `/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root`

Comment: muchas gracias me ha funcionado, solo lo queria para bloquear el formateo del disco del sistema operativo

Comment: de nada, ya sabes :-)  Si es para tu uso particular en un sistema controlado y que conoces donde estan los archivos del sistema pues vale... pero no te fies al 100% en todos los otros sistemas donde quieras usarlo... comprueba primero donde ubican su `/` por si acaso :-)  Saludos!

Comment: hay un problema tambien me coge los sdb, sdc, etc y solo quiero que me coga los sda

Comment: ah si?  jolin, a ver...  Pues a mi no me lo coje... voy a revisar hacia atras a ver de donde sacas los sda...

Comment: es un proyecto que estoy haciendo tiene 9 partes entre ellas la configuracion de un servidor web y me falta esto solo :)

Comment: diría que no es obligatorio... no entiendo el problema que estás teniendo... a mi me funciona bien si pongo `sdb`, tan solo que muestra `Esto no funciona` porque lo tienes puesto así, pero entiendo que allí le pondrás lo del formato en algun momento.

Comment: muchas gracias ya lo he solucionado resulta que lo tenia con corchetes ``if [[ $ELIMIDISCO =~ ^[sda] ]]`` y no me di cuenta que es asi ``if [[ $ELIMIDISCO =~ ^sda ]];``

Comment: ah, vale, porque lo que ahora habias puesto en la pregunta me estaba funcionando bien, je... revierte la pregunta a la inicial para que se entienda la respuesta, gracias

Comment: listo y muchas gracias

Comment: vaya, ahora que lo ejecuto del todo veo que si me sale el `sda` y no aquello del `/dev/mapper/vgubuntu-root` que te decia antes (y que habia visto en un `df -h` de mi ubuntu)... aún así, no se si tu programa seria compatible con la gestión de discos que hace LVM, que enmascara esos nombres y entiendo que si lo ejecutas a pelo te lo puedes cargar... no se como deberías filtrar eso, si es que necesitas hacerlo o ya te está bien así.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias